# Price filter showing prices excluding taxes

Tags: magento2, price, tax

Facing some issue for pricing filter, Maybe someone has a good solution for this issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7199.
I would be appreciated if someone could share the temporary fix.

Comment: Have you find the solution ? @Nicholad Miller